# How to add my own action to be triggered when user places a new order and remove the email action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to be able to **customize WooCommerce** to add my own action which is to be triggered when a user makes a purchase after checkout is complete.

I'd like this action to replace the generated confirmation email but I still want to make use of the variables generated for the email.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just edit the email templates, or if you want more functionality you can setup some events. This was in my bookmarks - https://www.storeapps.org/customize-woocommerce-emails/ and helped me before.